# Rails 3.1 :has_many, :through complex ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an orders model with line_items and vendors. When displaying an order, I want to group line_items by vendors.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :vendors, :through => :line_items
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end
```

I want to display a sorted list of vendors and line items:

```
You have placed an order for the following items:

  Vendor 1
    Line item 1
    Line item 2
    Line item 3

  Vendor 2
    Line Item 4
    Line Item 5

  ...
```

My current thought is

```
order.vendors.each do |a_vendor|
  a_vendor.name
  !!?? AND THEN WHAT GOES HERE ??!!
end
```

please help. I can't figure this out. maybe this could be done by sorting?

If the order only has one vendor, then I only want to show the one vendor.

Comment: a_vendor.line_items should work

Comment: @dbKooper - the vendor may have line_items from other orders

Comment: ok i got that now..
it's a has_many through items..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
<% @order.line_items.all.group_by{|i| i.vendor}.each do |vendor, items| %>
  <%= content_tag :h2, vendor.id %>
  <ul>
  <% items.each do |i| %>
       <%= content_tag :li, i.id %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

#### [edits]

sort_by(&:vendor) is the same as sort_by{|v| v.vendor}, but the block-style syntax gives you a little more flexibility.  For example, you can sort by vendor name in the controller with:

```
@sorted = @order.line_items.all.group_by(&:vendor).sort_by{|vendor, items| vendor.name}
```

Then in the view:

```
<% @sorted.each do |vendor, items| %>
  <%= content_tag :h2, vendor.name %>
  <ul>
  <% items.each do |i| %>
       <%= content_tag :li, i.id %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: nice but what if the OP wants to do eg `vendor.name`?

Comment: he could call vendor.name :)  It's not terribly efficient, but should be fine as long as there aren't hundreds of line items in an order

Comment: this looks very good... but what is the difference between:

`group_by{|i| i.vendor}`
and

`group_by(&:vendor)`
? I'm seeing it both ways online right now... and don't see a difference per se when i'm testing the code?

is one way deprecated?

Comment: ALSO: how can I sort the order of the vendors by their name attribute? `group_by{|i| i.vendor}.order('name')` doesn't work... thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, can sort in the model by adding an SQL snippet
to the :order option of the has_many association.

(See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :order => "item_number"
  has_many :vendors, :through => :line_items, :order => "name"
end
```

Then your view is very simple:

```
<% @order.vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <h3><%= vendor.name %></h3>
  <ul>
    <% vendor.line_items.where(:order_id=>@order.id).each do |item| %>
      <li><%= item.description %></li>
    <% end -%>
  </ul>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: I think you want vendor.line_items.where(:order_id=>@order.id)

Comment: hi richardsun, klochner is right... `vendor.line_items.each` will not work since line_items can come from many many different orders. but klochner's approach should work, and his comment here, too!

Comment: The answer has been edited to include the correction -- thanks!

Comment: thanks! that looks great. appreciated. I LOVE Ruby and Rails following the PERL'ism... there's more than one way to do it. :)