# How do i remove the dupes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have this loop in rails

```
 - @companies.people.each do |person|
  %p
    Hello there :
    = "#{person.manager.name} (#{person.manager.email})"
```

but i only want to print the managers name once.....but lots of people have the same manager and they are printing dupes...any idea how to not print dupes here

Comment: are you looking for something similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793152/rails-3-1-has-many-through-complex-ordering

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't you rather do:

```
@companies.managers do |manager|
...
```

So you need to amend the underlying model (Company?) with a `managers` method. And whether that's done via a scope, or a model relation or alfonso's brute force answer, we don't have enough information to determine. But in any case this logic is best tucked away in the model and not exposed in the view.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Company
  scope :managers, ->(){where(manager: true)}
end

module EmployeeListViewHelper
  def manager_list
    Company.managers.each do |m|
      content_tag(:p, "Hello There : #{m.name} #{m.email}")
    end
  end
end
```

Then just this in your view:

```
= manager_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you're going about this probably the wrong way. If you don't want the manager's name duplicated for each person, you might have to group people under managers.

Your view then should look hierarchical, people under the manager should be visually placed like that, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the `uniq` method:

```
@companies.people.map{|p| p.manager}.uniq
```